# Begin running cron job on npm prestart

Tags: node.js, cron, npm-scripts, node-cron

I need to begin a cron job every time before I start my app. So in my `package.json`, I have the following scripts:

```
"prestart": "node ./scripts/pre-start",
"start": "node server.js",
```

This is my prestart script:

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob

function preStart () {
  console.log('in the prestart function')
  const job = new CronJob('* * * * * *', function () {
    console.log('You will see this message every second')
  }, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles')
  job.start()
}

preStart()
module.export = preStart
```

The issue is that I am getting stuck in my prestart (never get to run `server.js` from the start script)and all I wanted this to do is to run the cron job in the background as a I run my app.

How can I just set up my cron job and then move on to executing my app?

Comment: I know it's been a pretty long time but have you found any solution to this?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros It's been so long I completely forgot about this thread and don't even remember what I was trying to do. I couldn't even tell  you if I found a solution or ended up doing something completely different :( Sorry! Wish I had more to offer.